# unable to understand how inequality was derived

Tags: inequality

I'm reading a paper which essentially shows the following calculation (I've modified variable names for simplicity):
$ x \sim \frac{m_1}{m_1 + m_2} \left(1 + \frac{T_1}{T_2}\frac{m_2}{m_1}\right)^{1/2}$

We are told that $T_1 \geq T_2$ always, and thus the author concludes:
$x \gtrsim \sqrt{\frac{m_1}{(m_1+m_2)}}$

$T_{1,2}$ and $m_{1,2}$ are $> 0$.

My attempt:
Let $M \equiv m_1 + m_2$, then taking $\sqrt{m_1/M}$ inside the $(...)^{1/2}$,

$x \sim \sqrt{\frac{m_1}{M}}\left(\frac{m_1}{M} + \frac{T_1}{T_2}\frac{m_2}{M}\right)^{1/2}$

The quantity in the brackets is always $> \sqrt{m_1/M}$ and so I find that

$x \gtrsim \frac{m_1}{M}$, whereas the result above says $x \gtrsim \sqrt{\frac{m_1}{M}}$

What am I missing?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Consider that if $T_1 \geq T_2$, then it follows that $\frac{T_1}{T_2} \geq \frac{1}{1}$; what would happen if you simplified from there?

Comment: you are a bit behind the times. strugglinggrad is now called Volgograd.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to all those who gave answers! I think I understand it now:

$x \sim \frac{m_1}{M}\left(\frac{m_1 + \alpha m_2}{m_1}\right)^{1/2} \gtrsim \frac{m_1}{M}\left(\frac{m_1 + m_2}{m_1}\right)^{1/2} \\ \Rightarrow x \gtrsim \left(\frac{m_1}{M}\right)^{1/2}$

(given that $\alpha = T_1/T_2 \geq 1, M = m_1 + m_2$)

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that
$$\frac{x}{x+y}\left(1+\alpha \frac{y}{x}\right)^{1/2}\geq C\,\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+y}}$$
for $\alpha\in [1,+\infty[$, $x,y>0$. So you want to show that
$$\left(\frac{x}{x+y}\left(1+\alpha \frac{y}{x}\right)\right)^{1/2}$$
is minored by a positive constant for $\alpha\in [1,+\infty[$, $x,y>0$.

So it's enough to show that
$$\frac{x}{x+y}\left(1 +\frac{y}{x}\right)=1$$
is minored by a positive constant for $x,y>0$.